# MS-Access subform with continuous form issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on access forms(MS access 2010). I created one form, that shows record one by one when i set **default view -> Continuous Forms**
     I getting a trouble when i use that form as sub form to another form. Am getting single form view in another form. Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you have your Parent and Child links defined?  If so, what are they?  If those are correct, can you view the subform as a continuous form on its own?

Answer (score 1):

Put something like this in your code to set the default view of your subform:

```
Forms!frmMain.frmSubform.DefaultView = 2
```